# print invoice controller file location in admin

Tags: admin, invoice

i want to know the controller or block file location that is being used to generate pdf invoice using button print in this file. please see image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The location is `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\PrintAction` .
The method is `execute()`, that is implemented in `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction` .

Comment: Hello @Vixent
Where is block file and layout file located ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. Maybe in `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\...` (search in folder `/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice` )